# Problem with SSAS connection with my ASP.NET web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssas

I'm creating a web service that reads a file that contains a XMLA query and execute it against SSAS. My problem is that everything works locally, but when I publish my solution on a Windows Server 2008 R2 an exception keeps being generated.

Here is my code:

```
    private String sendXMLARequest(String sXMLARequest, String sTargetServer, StreamWriter logger)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(sXMLARequest);
        String Json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
        Server server = new Server();
        server.Connect(sTargetServer);
        server.Execute(sXMLARequest);
        XmlaResultCollection rsCollection = server.Execute(sXMLARequest);
        string dis = server.Version.ToString();
        String s = null;
        foreach (XmlaResult res in rsCollection)
        {

            s += res.Value.ToString();
            foreach (XmlaMessage message in res.Messages)
            {
                logger.WriteLine(message.ToString());
                if (message is XmlaError)
                   Json = s + "ERROR : " + message.Description;
                else
                   Json = s + "WARNIN   : " + message.Description;
            }
        }
        server.Disconnect();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();   
        return js.Serialize(Json.ToString()); ;
    }
```

> EXCEPTION :  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: A
>   connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: If the SSAS server is on a different machine, I'd make sure that the identity the application pool is running under on IIS has network privileges and can connect to the SSAS server.

Comment: i cheked for that but the problem still remain the same !!

Comment: Perhaps the server's IP address is blocked at some point between it and SSAS.